# Mongo C# bulk upserts performance issues

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-csharp-2.0

Currently I am working on CSV imports with mongo and c#.

```
var contractModels = listContracts.Select(item =>
                            new ReplaceOneModel<UsaSpendingsContract>(
                                    new ExpressionFilterDefinition<UsaSpendingsContract>(doc =>
                                        doc.PageUrl == item.PageUrl),
                                    item)
                            { IsUpsert = true });
var bulkWriteResult = await _contractsCollection.BulkWriteAsync(contractModels, new BulkWriteOptions { IsOrdered = false });
```

Above is the code, when I read the csv file and batch a list of 1000 records at a time and try to insert them in the mongo db.

I have about 30 million records to insert.

If the collection size goes beyond 500k records the writes slow down tremendously, like 1000 records take upto 20 mins to write!

As such I keep draining the collection once it reaches 200k records. Doing this keeps the 1k write under 5 mins.

At this rate I am able to insert 1 million records in 16 hrs!

Can some one please guide me in the right direction here?

I am using c# with Asp net core 2.2 and mongo db c# driver v 2.9.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add server version and deployment topology to the question. Identify whether the time is being spent in your application or database, and whether the bottleneck is CPU or disk.

Comment: This is on my local machine, as such is a personal project where I am just trying to collect and analyse the data from a public API which serves huge csv files. This is a mongo community v 4.2.2 . I have timers in my code, where I track when the request goes to mongo and comes back in and it looks like mongo is taking up all the time. Regarding the CPU or disk bottleneck how do you check? Also, this is running on an SSD plus a 6 core core i7 with 32 gb ram.

Comment: CPU usage & iowait time would be a quick way.